# Ordering array so item with null value appears last

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following Tweet array:

```
tweets: [{
    "body": "RT blah blah blah",
    "image": "",
    "screen_name": "billsmith",
    "timestamp": "2016-02-28 08:19:02"
}, {
    "body": "RT blah blah blah",
    "image": "http://www.image.com",
    "screen_name": "JoeBloggs_",
    "timestamp": "2016-06-28 07:37:40"
}]
```

How do I orderby image so that tweets with images appear first? So basically I want tweets with `"image": ""` to appear last.

I've tried the following function to reorder the items but it doesn't work:

```
  tweets.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.image - b.image;
  });
```

Any ideas much appreciated. I am happy to use a solution that uses plain JavaScript or lodash.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sort()` like this.

```js
var tweets = [{
  "body": "RT blah blah blah",
  "image": "",
  "screen_name": "billsmith",
  "timestamp": "2016-02-28 08:19:02"
}, {
  "body": "RT blah blah blah",
  "image": "http://www.image.com",
  "screen_name": "JoeBloggs_",
  "timestamp": "2016-06-28 07:37:40"
}]

tweets.sort(function(a, b) {
  if (b.image.length) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }
})

console.log(tweets)
```

Answer (score 0):

This proposal sorts only filled strings to top and empty strings to bottom, without any other sorting.

```js
var tweets = [{ body: "RT blah blah blah", image: "", screen_name: "billsmith", timestamp: "2016-02-28 08:19:02" }, { body: "RT blah blah blah", image: "http://www.image.com", screen_name: "JoeBloggs_", timestamp: "2016-06-28 07:37:40" }];

tweets.sort(function(a, b) {
      return !a.image - !b.image;
});

console.log(tweets);
```

Comment: This sorts by image url, which was not requested by OP, so perhaps not desirable. The answer by Nenad Vracar is cleaner IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tweets = [{
  "body": "RT blah blah blah",
  "image": "",
  "screen_name": "billsmith",
  "timestamp": "2016-02-28 08:19:02"
},{
  "body": "RT blah blah blah",
  "screen_name": "billsmith",
  "timestamp": "2016-02-28 08:19:02"
}, {
  "body": "RT blah blah blah",
  "image": "http://www.image.com",
  "screen_name": "JoeBloggs_",
  "timestamp": "2016-06-28 07:37:40"
}]

tweets.sort(function(a, b) {
  return !a.image || a.image === "" ? 1 : -1;
})

console.log(tweets)
```